# Kdevelop crashes when opening file?

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I am using a project developed by someone else. I am trying to open one of the source files, but KDevelop crashes before I can change anything or crashes immediately after typing one or two characters.
I was able to make some changes in the beginning, but now it crashes.
I have tried to close the sessions, I re-installed kdevelop, I copied file content to a new file, I erased the .kde folder in home directory, nothing seems to help.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the size of the file? What version of `KDevelop` are you running? If its an older version, try upgrading, hoping that the issue was fixed :-)

Comment: I am using Version 4.10.5 and .cpp file that makes problems has size 19.2KB.

Comment: Does this happend with any other file?

Comment: No! I can modify all other files. I was able to modify problematic .cpp file, but since yesterday it is impossible.

Comment: @user3616359 Have you tried the same with the latest stable release i.e. 4.6.0?

Comment: Try another editor, lets say `nano` or `vim`. Maybe you have low memory and Kdevelop crash when indexing the file?  If you try with those editors and don't works neither, well, the problem isn't Kdevelop.

Comment: @HAL I installed 4.6.0, and now it works. But in order to do that, I have upgraded OS. Thanks!

Comment: @user3616359: Please close this question, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer